# Installation of npm fails

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Installation of npm fails. However I am able to see node-modules folder is generated in my local path. How to resolve the issue in the above image

[Click here to see the installation error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvCzG.png)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing python 2 dependency for node-gyp

Heres some documentation on node environment for windows, including the required python 2 installation 
https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules